# Lazy evaluation in Matlab's logical indexing

Tags: matlab

I wonder if Matlab uses lazy evaluation when I am doing something like:

```
sum(points.power(points.object == 5 & points.x .^2 + points.y .^2 < r^2))
```

The idea here is to calculate the power of all points on object 5 provided that those points are within r from (0, 0). The points structure is like this:

```
points.object = [...]
points.x = [...]
points.y = [...]
points.power [...]
```

I hope Matlab will not evaluate x^2+y^2 for those points that do not belong to object 5, for the same reason it will not evaluate the second part of `2>3 && 3>4`. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I think you are mixing up [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) and [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

It is important to understand that `&&` and `&` are different operators. The `&&` operator [allows for short-circuiting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html#bt_0nai-1) and this behavior is contingent upon each input evaluating to a `logical` scalar.

The [`&`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html) operator on the other hand, accepts two arrays as input and performs an element-wise `and` between the two arrays. In order to do this element-wise comparison, it *will evaluate the statements on either side of the operator* before performing the operation. Your statement is the equivalent of:

```
and(points.object == 5, points.x.^2 + points.y.^2 < r^2)
```

Where `points.object == 5` and `point.x.^2 + points.y.^2 < r^2` are both evaluated to yield `logical` arrays.

If you want to restrict the calculation of the second component to only elements where the first part of the conditional is `true`, you can break it up into multiple statements and use logical indexing from the first statement to determine the elements for which the second statement is evaluated.

```
touse = points.object == 5;
touse(touse) = (points.x(touse).^2 + points.y(touse).^2) < r^2;

output = sum(points.power(touse));
```

It's important to note that this isn't necessarily going to be any faster since there is now some additional indexing being performed.

That being said, if you're doing this within a loop and are concerned about performance when you want to compare multiple `point.object` values and `r` values, you could pre-compute `points.x.^2 + points.y.^2` outside of the loop. In this scenario you could also just go ahead and compute the square root of this value so you don't have to square `r` every time through the loop either.

```
% Pre-compute this so you only have to perform this operation once for each element
R = sqrt(points.x .^ 2 + points.y .^ 2);

for k = 1:5
    % Use the pre-computed value in your conditional
    value(k) = sum(points.power(points.object == k & R < r));
end
```

Comment: Also pointing out this has nothing to do with lazy evaluation.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou haha yea. I just added a statement about that to the beginning.